# Why are untyped properties in a domain class not rendered to JSON

Tags: json, grails

Why is there a difference when I render the following domain class

```
class Foo {
    String code
}
```

and this

```
class Foo {
    def code
}
```

If I render an instance of this in a restful controller

```
def show() {
    respond new Foo(code: "some_value")
}
```

The first example will render as

```
 {"class":"Foo","id":null,"code":"some_value"}
```

where as the second example will render only as

```
 {"class":"Foo","id":null}
```

Comment: I suspect because the marshaller doesn't know what data type to use, so it ignores it.